# grails 3 no logging in console

Tags: grails, logging, logback

My project in grails stop to print loggings in console like how it did before although I havn't changed the file logback.groovy. When I use something like `log.info 'Searching for ...'` in environment development there in nothing in console.

I am in grails 3.2.8 and IntelliJ 2017.2.

Here is the logback.groovy :

```
import grails.util.BuildSettings
import grails.util.Environment
import org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.ColorConverter
import org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.WhitespaceThrowableProxyConverter

import java.nio.charset.Charset

conversionRule 'clr', ColorConverter
conversionRule 'wex', WhitespaceThrowableProxyConverter

// See http://logback.qos.ch/manual/groovy.html for details on configuration
appender('STDOUT', ConsoleAppender) {
    encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) {
        charset = Charset.forName('UTF-8')

        pattern =
                '%clr(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}){faint} ' + // Date
                        '%clr(%5p) ' + // Log level
                        '%clr(---){faint} %clr([%15.15t]){faint} ' + // Thread
                        '%clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} ' + // Logger
                        '%m%n%wex' // Message
    }
}

def targetDir = BuildSettings.TARGET_DIR
if (Environment.isDevelopmentMode() && targetDir != null) {
    appender("FULL_STACKTRACE", FileAppender) {
        file = "${targetDir}/stacktrace.log"
        append = true
        encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) {
            pattern = "%level %logger - %msg%n"
        }
    }
    logger("StackTrace", ERROR, ['FULL_STACKTRACE'], false)
    root(INFO, ['STDOUT', 'FULL_STACKTRACE'])
}
else {
    root(TRACE, ['STDOUT'])
}
```

Comment: Please try to add "logger("[yourProjectName]", DEBUG, ['STDOUT'], false)" to your logback file (insert your project name/root directory name)

Comment: I try to add a logger `logger("dn-rider", DEBUG, ['STDOUT'], false)` just after the first logger but it doesn't work. 'dn-rider' is the name the project. I don't understand the first parameter of the function logger, what do you mean 'project name/root dic name' ? Thanks !